# Why I get negative value of condensed Fukui functions?

Tags: electronic-structure

**Hello there,**

I'm trying to calculate condensed Fukui functions for atoms of ascorbate (anion!). For some reason, when calculating nucleophilicity, the functions are negative. The equation I use is:
$$
\tag{1}
f_A^- = P_A(N) - P_A(N-1)
$$

First of all, please confirm whether I am correct - since anion is being examined, `N` is the anion charges and `N-1` is the radical (`0 2`) charges?

Here are charges I obtained from Hirshfeld population analysis for N, N-1 and calculated condensed Fukui function:

[image: Charges and fukui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, about the signs. There's nothing odd with having summed partial charges of -1 and 0 for a single anion and a neutral molecule, respectively, since the sum is just the charge state of your system. Even in the neutral system some individual partial charges will be negative, and others positive; this is determined by the relative electronegativities of the atoms.

Since you want to look at the population of electrons, not elementary charge, you might want to flip the sign of your Fukui function; $f_+({\bf r}) = \rho_{N+1}({\bf r})-\rho_N({\bf r})$ is defined in terms of electron densities $\rho$, not charge densities $-\rho$.

Now, about the method. Hirshfeld analysis is well-known to yield unreliable partial charges. Instead of the original scheme, which is dependent on a set of reference atom densities, improved alternatives such as the iterative Hirshfeld method, [J. Chem. Phys. 126, 144111 (2007)](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.2715563), and its later developments like the minimal-basis iterative Stockholder method, [J. Chem. Theory Comput. 12, 3894 (2016)](https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.jctc.6b00456), might yield better results.

Comment: I asked about charges purely in the matter of Gaussian input - wasn't sure whether `0 2` is correct for N-1, when N-electron system is `-1 1`.

So the electron density () is negative of charge density (−)...? And just flip the sign of the result of Fukui function? But my equation for nucleophilicity is ok, isn't it? I'm messed now, because you sent different (for electrophilicity?).

I have read in one article that Hirshfeld analysis is basis-set independent. Gaussian doesn't seem to distinguish iterative from non-iterative. There's just Hirshfeld (https://gaussian.com/population/)

Comment: If you look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fukui_function, the nucleophilic Fukui function for the neutral molecule is the same as the electrofilic Fukui function for the anion.

Comment: `0 2` is correct for a neutral molecule in a doublet state, and `-1 1` for a single anion in a singlet state.

Comment: There are many mathematically well-posed charge analyses; the only ones you should stay away from are Mulliken and Löwdin that don't even have a basis set limit.

To use the newer Hirschfeld methods, you might have to rely on a third party addon to Gaussian.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: One more question - I have found such statement concerning condensed Fukui functions: "The Fukui function can be used to describe local chemical reactivity. This can even be done per atom by using the condensed Fukui function. Atomic charges are used to get the condensed Fukui function."... Atomic charges?  (https://www.scm.com/doc/GUI/Fukui.html)

Comment: Atomic charges == partial charges.